# SML: Type inference giving strange error whilst appending an item to a list

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am trying to reverse a list in SML with the following implementation

```
 fun reverse x y =
      case x of
         [] => y
       | x::xs => reverse(xs, x::y)
 ;
```

The error messages I get is impenetrable:

```
trial.sml:1.6-4.35 Error: case object and rules don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  rule domain: 'Z list * 'Z list
  object: ('Z list * 'Z list) * 'Y
  in expression:
    (case (arg,arg)
      of (x,y) =>
           (case x
             of nil => y
              | :: <pat> => reverse <exp>))
trial.sml:1.6-4.35 Error: right-hand-side of clause doesn't agree with function result type [tycon mismatch]
  expression:  'Z -> _
  result type:  'Y list
  in declaration:
    reverse = (fn arg => (fn <pat> => <exp>))
```

However if I change the signature to be fun reverse(x: 'a list, y: 'a list)
then it works why is this so? Is there a way to write this so that I dont need to have to write the type 'a list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x y` differs from `(x,y)`.

In the first line of the definition

```
fun reverse x y =
```

You seem to be trying to write a *curried* function of type

```
fn: a' list -> a' list -> 'a list
```

but in the recursive call

```
reverse(xs, x::y)
```

you are treating `reverse` as if it were and *uncurried* function of type

fn: a' list * a' list -> 'a list

The problem has nothing at all to do with whether or not you add a type annotation but instead it has to do with where you put parenthesis (and commas, if any). There are two valid fixes depending on what you want the type to be. Since this seems to be homework (there is no obvious non-homework reason to avoid the built-in `rev`), I'll leave the details to you.

Comment: oh!! noo im wasnt intending to write a curried function I see why its getting confusing. I didnt know the brackes and commas made a difference. Thanks for your help.